# Extracting a word containing a symbol from a string in Java

Tags: java, regex

The basic idea is that I want to pull out any part of the string with the form "text1.text2". Some examples of the input and output of what I'd like to do would be:

```
"employee.first_name" ==> "employee.first_name"
"2 * employee.salary AS double_salary" ==> "employee.salary"
```

Thus far I have just .split(" ") and then found what I needed and .split("."). Is there any cleaner way?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Something like `(\w+\.\w+)` (see http://regexr.com?36h6d)

Comment: Thus far I have just .split(" ") and then found what I needed and .split("."). It's a pathetic work around, I feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with an actual `Pattern` and an iterative find, instead of splitting the `String`.

For instance:

```
String test = "employee.first_name 2 * ... employee.salary AS double_salary blabla e.s blablabla";
// searching for a number of word characters or puctuation, followed by dot, 
// followed by a number of word characters or punctuation
// note also we're avoiding the "..." pitfall
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\p{Punct}&&[^\\.]]+\\.[\\w\\p{Punct}&&[^\\.]]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
employee.first_name
employee.salary
e.s
```

Note: to simplify the `Pattern` you could only list the allowed punctuation forming your "."-separated words in the categories

For instance:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w_]+\\.[\\w_]+");
```

This way, `foo.bar*2` would be matched as `foo.bar`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `split` to break the string into fragments.Then search for `.` in each of those fragments using `contains` method, to get the desired fragments:

Here you go:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "2 * employee.salary AS double_salary";
    String arr[] = str.split("\\s");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].contains(".")) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to the way I do it already, and I was hoping there was something simpler. Is it possible to perhaps include this functionality: "2*employee.salary AS double_salary" ==> "employee.salary", where we know there will be some symbol and possibly number we want pulled directly off? (eg "2*employee.salary" or "employee.salary*2")

Answer (score 0):

```
String mydata = "2 * employee.salary AS double_salary";
pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+\\.\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if (matcher.find())
{
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in JAVA, but as I used regex in python and based on internet tutorials, I offer you to use `r'(\S*)\.(\S*)'` as the pattern. I tried it in python and it worked well in your example.

But if you want to use multiple dots continuously, it has a bug. I mean if you are trying to match something like `first.second.third`, this pattern identifies `('first.second', 'third')` as the matched group and I think it relates to the best match strategy.